# Postgres connection problems using Google Cloud VPC connector

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have the following topology:

1. App engine Java application
2. VPC connector (10.8.0.0)
3. Compute engine that has Postgresql running inside

Java(Spring Boot) establishs a JDBC connection to the Postgresql using internal IP via VPC connector. It starts fine but after a minute or so I get:
`org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@68dca69f marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(0)`

If I connect App engine to the Compute engine directly via External public IP avoiding VPC connector then it works just fine for hours.

It's very annoying and I couldn't find anything useful in the Google documentation.

NOTE: I am using default network for compute engine and for app engine

NOTE 2: in app.yaml I have specified connector as following: vpc_access_connector:
name: "projects/{projectid}/locations/us-central1/connectors/{connector-name}"

NOTE 3: I have followed https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access

Comment: Hi,  Have you seen this: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access it seems there is everything explained, try to follow and let us know

Comment: I did exactly 1-1 as said in the documentation:  https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access

Comment: What's your connexion string?

Comment: jdbc:postgresql://10.128.0.2:5432/db_name